# Export cell data from google drive to CSV

Tags: excel, vba, google-drive-api

I have a google drive folder with a lot of excel files, and I need to get the data from some specific cells into a csv file. I have a macro to do that but I have to go file by file to run the macro and get the data. The data I need is always on the same number cell on each file. Is there a way to extract the data without going file by file? Is ok if I need to download the files but I need to save time without going one by one.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google drive api is a file storage api only (list, create, delete, update files). It has no ability to access the data within the files themselves.

If you convert the csv files to google sheets you could use the google sheets api to access the data.

Comment: thanks, that what I was afraid of. I will have to download the files and run a macro locally to get the data.